# Let $p,q$ be 2 complex numbers with $|p|<|q|$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

> Let $p,q$ be 2 complex numbers with $|p|<|q|$. Let $$f(z)=\sum\{3p^n-5q^n\}z^n$$  Then the radius of convergence of $f(z)$ is :
>
> 1. $|q|$
> 2. $|p|$
> 3. At least $\frac{1}{|q|}$
> 4. At most $\frac{1}{|q|}$

*My Attempt*: $f(z)=\sum(3p^n-5q^n)z^n=\sum\{3p^n\}z^n-\sum\{5q^n\}z^n=3\sum(pz)^n-5\sum(qz)^n$. Now for convergence,we must have $|pz|<1 \implies |z|<\frac{1}{|p|}$ and $|qz|<1 \implies |z|<\frac{1}{|q|}$. Also we are given that $|p|<|q| \implies \frac{1}{|q|} <\frac{1}{|p|}$.

Now,I am bit confused. Can someone help? Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically done: just think about the following.

If you want the series for $f$ to converge, then you'd better get the two series you got by splitting $f$ to *both* converge. If $|z|<1/|p|$, then the $p^nz^n$ series will converge, but is this enough to get the $q^nz^n$ series to converge? If $|z|<1/|q|$, will the $p^nz^n$ series converge?

Comment: I am confused about  the terms  atleast or atmost....

Comment: Well, can $\sum q^nz^n$ converge when $|z|\geq 1/|q|$?

Comment: Oh..I have got it..So it should be at most $\frac{1}{|q|}$.Am I right?

Comment: Yes. "At most" is important, because the radius of convergence cannot be exactly $1/|q|$.

Answer (score 0):

You are there.  You are correct about the two limits on $|z|$.  You need both limits to be satisfied, so need to take the more restrictive limit.  Your next to last line shows this is $\frac 1{|q|}$